# TypeError: React.__spread is not a function (React 16 with babel 6)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

Using node.js with babel as follows:

```
require('babel-core/register')({presets: ['react']});
```

With the following versions:

```
"babel-core": "6.26.0"
"babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
```

I get the above error.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `babel-preset-es2015` and update babel register like

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});
```

Comment: @Daniel it seems the order of transforms are important, i updated my answer, can you try it out, this should trigger the `spread` transform before `react` ones

Comment: Thanks but still the same

Comment: @Daniel interesting, unfortunately i have no more idea's left